# 2d Triangle with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, 2d, opengl-es-2.0

**EDIT 2:** Take a look on the [Triangle2d sample](https://github.com/ibraim-gm/opengles2-2d-demos/blob/master/src/ibraim/opengles2/Triangle2dActivity.java) of [this GitHub project](https://github.com/ibraim-gm/opengles2-2d-demos) for a complete, working sample.

**EDIT:** See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203877/851863) for a link with a good explanation on how the ortographic matrix works. In the end, I tweaked the provided code a little:

```
  float[] mvp = {
     2f/width,   0f,         0f, 0f,
     0f,        -2f/height,  0f, 0f,
     0f,         0f,         0f, 0f,
    -1f,         1f,         0f, 1f
   };
```

Please note that my z is fixed in 0 and w fixed in 1. This matrix make the origin (0,0) at the bottom-left of the screen; if you want the origin at top-left, try:

```
  float[] mvp = {
     2f/width,   0f,         0f, 0f,
     0f,         2f/height,  0f, 0f,
     0f,         0f,         0f, 0f,
    -1f,        -1f,         0f, 1f
   };
```

Another problem was the call to `GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv` which I changed to:

```
FloatBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(mvp.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
b.put(mvp).position(0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMvpPos, b.limit() / mvp.length, false, b);
```

If you want to mess with this a bit, try [this online calculator](http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/matrix_multiplication.aspx). Just remember that the **rows in your sorce file** will be **columns in the calculator**.

**Original Problem:**
I'm trying to draw a 2d triangle using OpenGLES 2.0 on android, but so far, not much success. These are my shaders:

```
(Vertex shader)
uniform mat4    uMvp;
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec3 aColor;
varying vec4 vColor;
void main() {
  vColor = vec4(aColor.xyz, 1.0);
  vec4 position = vec4(aPosition.xyz, 1.0);
  gl_Position = uMvp * position;
};

(Fragment shader)
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 vColor;
void main(void)
{
  gl_FragColor = vColor;
};
```

Then, in the onSurfaceChanged method of GLSurfaceView.Renderer, I put the following:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
{
  // here I load and compile the shaders and link the program.
  // in the end, I use GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);
  // (code omitted)

  // create the matrix for the uniform
  int uMvpPos = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "uMvp");
  float[] mvp = {width, 0f, 0f, 0f,
                 0f, -height, 0f, 0f,
                 0f, 0f, -2f, 0f,
                 -1f, 1, -1f, 1};
  GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(uMvpPos, mvp.length * 4, false, mvp, 0);

  // set viewport and clear color to white
  GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  GLES20.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f,1.0f);
}
```

I used the values of the matrix showed on [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4309/opengl-es-2-0-setting-up-2d-projection/4312#4312). My intent here is to work with coordinates in the same way as a canvas works: (0,0) on top-left of screen and (width, height) on bottom-right.

And last but not least, this is the code of onDrawFrame:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
{
  int aPos = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle,"aPosition");
  int aColor = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle,"aColor");

  // assuming I correctly set up my coordinate system,
  // these are the triangle coordinates and color
  float[] data =
      {
        // XYZ, RGB
        100f, 100f, 0f,
        1f, 0f, 0f,

        50f, 50f, 0f,
        1f, 0f, 0f,

        150f, 50f, 0f,
        1f, 0f, 0f,
      };

  // put all my data into a float buffer
  // the '* 4' is because a float has 4 bytes
  FloatBuffer dataVertex = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
  dataVertex.put(data).position(0);

  // set the POSITION values
  // attribute, dataSize(number of elements), data type, normalized?, size(bytes), data
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPos);
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPos, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 6 * 4, dataVertex);

  // set the COLOR values
  dataVertex.position(3); // offset
  GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColor);
  GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aColor, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 6 * 4, dataVertex);

  // put a white background
  GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // and finally draw the triangle!
  GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

The end result is... a boring white screen, without the triangle. I guess I'm committing a very simple mistake, but I just can't spot it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your orthographic projection matrix is wrong.
[Orthographic projection is defined as](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) (in column major order):

```
2/(r-l), 0, 0, 0,
0, 2/(t-b), 0, 0,
0, 0, 2/(f-n), 0,
(r+l)/(l-r), (t+b)/(b-t), (f+n)/(n-f), 1
```

In your case `r=0, l=width, t=height, b=0, f=1, n=0` and you get:

```
-2/width, 0, 0, 0,
0, 2/height, 0, 0,
0, 0, 2, 0,
1, -1, -1, 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Since my z and w are fixed (I'm interested only in 2d here) I did a little tweaking on the matrix and everything is fine now. The call to glUniformMatrix4fv was wrong too. I will edit the original question to reflect that.